# C# the creation of new X509certificate using pfx file is not working

Tags: c#, .net, api, ssl, pfx

Loading of the pfx certificate does not pass and gives me a path error.
I'm documenting this problem since two days now and I still haven't been able to get my C# code to work.

To begin, I have 3 files .pem and .crt and .key to call an API from an Application Pool using C# . I tested it using cURL and it worked,
command : `Curl -X GET -v URI --proxy PROXY --CaCert CRTPATH --key KEYPATH --cert PEMPATH`

I relied then on the .Net documentation to know the steps to call an API. First I started by generating a .pfx file, command :`openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt` this conversion was don using a password.
I also give the pool the necessary permissions to read the pfx certificate from local storage, and enble the user profile loading.

The problem is happening in the X509Certificate generation phase in my C# code, returning an unrecognized path error and I believe that the error does not point the real problem.
code : `X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(CertificatePath);`  noting that I'm using the relative path @"C:\folder\certificate.pfx".
I also tried introducing the password I had to use during the certificate conversion, code : `X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(CertificatePath, key);`  declaring first key as a string.
And I tried to change my path to "C:\\folder\\certificate.pfx". same the error still here.

information that could be useful, application pool uses the .Net 4.0 framework, and I have not specified a specific dll for my application.

If anyone has encountered this problem and was able to find a solution please share the solution you found.
or if you have any good documentation or links that explains something i missed please share them.

update: the error I'm having "The format of the given path is not supported"

Comment: "returning an unrecognized path error" can you update your question to include the exact exception? My general suspicion is that this isn't a particular issue with X509Certificate{2}. Can you read the file contents with `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes`?

Comment: yes I tried to read it using ReadAllBytes and it's generating the same error.

Comment: That answer is not clear enough. If you do a File.ReadAllBytes( yourpath ) on a seperate line of code does it throw on that line. If so it has nothing to do with the certificate as @vcsjones suggests